# How to generate a persistent TLS Fingerprint for the msmtp SMTP client

Tags: email, smtp

I am using msmtp as a mail client on an M1 iMac still running Monterey. I use Gmail as a relay.

It's been working fine, except recently I started getting the following error message:

```
send-mail: TLS certificate verification failed: the certificate fingerprint does not match
```

So, I generate a new fingerprint with this:

```
msmtp --serverinfo --tls --tls-certcheck=off --host=smtp.gmail.com --port=587 | egrep -o "([0-9A-Za-z]{2}:){31}[0-9A-Za-z]{2}"
```

And then it works, until it doesn't. In the last couple of days I've had to generate three new fingerprints.

Why do the fingerprints seem to expire and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method that works for me and avoids the issue of the tls_fingerprint expiring.

Use MacPorts to install the curl CA bundle:

`sudo port install curl-ca-bundle`

Locate the bundle:

```
port contents curl-ca-bundle

Port curl-ca-bundle contains:
  /opt/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Add the following line to .msmptrc

`tls_trust_file /opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt`

It works:

```
Hatchet:~ me$ mail me@mac.com
Subject: Hi Mike
done
.
EOT
```

No error. From the log file:

`exitcode=EX_OK`